# Question about an exercise concerning empty coproduct

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, coproduct

The question below is taken from Arrows, Structures and Functors by Arbib and Manes.

Can someone tell me if my solution is correct or if I am wrong, what am I not understanding or misinterpreting about the question.  Also, I read online that the empty coproduct (coproduct indexed by the empty set) is the same as an initial object in $C$ (denotes category).  I don't know what that means since I am still a beginner in category theory and the book I am using have not talked about initial or terminal objects.

> The interesting thing about general definitions is that they are often more general than you realize.  Consider what happens to $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ and $\coprod_{i\in I}A_i$ when $I=\emptyset$,
>
> $$\prod A_i=\{f|f:\emptyset \rightarrow \emptyset\}$$ and so have exactly one element.
> What is the empty coproduct?

Attempt solution.

Is the question asking if $I=\emptyset$ and set $A_\emptyset=\emptyset$, then what is $A\sqcup A$?.  In this case if we let $A'=\{(\emptyset,1)|\emptyset\in A\}$, then $A'\sqcup A'=\{(\emptyset,1)\}\cup\{(\emptyset,1)\}=\{(\emptyset,1)\}=\emptyset$

Thank you in advance

Comment: The question is asking what the coproduct of the empty diagram is, which is different than what your solution shows (it's not clear what your solution does show),

Comment: The empty coproduct is the colimit of the empty diagram. This is just the initial object, so $\emptyset$ in the case of $\mathsf{Set}$

Comment: @IsAdisplayName what does "the coproduct of the empty diagram" mean?

Comment: @Seth it's a standard phase in category theory. How does the book define coproducts?

Comment: @FShrike what does "empty coproduct is the colimit of the empty diagram" mean?  As I just told IsAdisplayName, The text I am using have not covered all these new words.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName my text defines product as follows:  A **product** of two sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ is a set $A$ equipped with two maps $\pi_1:A\rightarrow A_1$ and $\pi_2:A\rightarrow A_2$ (called **projections**) with the property that, given any other set $C$ with paire of maps $p_1:C\rightarrow A_1$ and $p_2:C\rightarrow A_2$, there exists a unique map $p$ such that $\pi_i\circ p=p_i$

Comment: Empty diagram just means you have 0 sets instead of the two $A_1$, $A_2$. Honestly, I recommend looking at a different text, like Emily Riehl's "Category Theory it Context"

Comment: @IsAdisplayName the empty coproduct is called an initial object in every categories?  Meaning category of sets, groups, vector spaces, etc etc?  Also why is it the same as the initial object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal property of the coproduct of indexed sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is this:

> "The" coproduct: $$\bigsqcup_{i\in I}A_i$$Is any set $\mathcal{A}$ with maps $\iota_i:A_i\hookrightarrow\mathcal{A}$ for all $i$, such that:
>
> > For any set $X$ and family of functions $A_i\overset{f_i}{\longrightarrow}X$, there is a **unique** function: $$\large\mathcal{A}=\bigsqcup_{i\in I}A_i\overset{\langle f_i\rangle}{\longrightarrow}X$$Such that: $$\langle f_i\rangle\circ\iota_j=f_j:A_j\to X,\quad\forall j\in I$$

So now let $I=\emptyset$. This is the meaning of 'empty coproduct'. What happens? We need to find a set $\mathcal{A}$ and... no functions at all, since there are no $A_i$... such that for every family of functions $f_i:A_i\to X$ - there is only one, the 'empty' family, existing for every set $X$ uniquely - we get a unique function $\mathcal{A}\to X$ for which... oh, there are no functions $f_i,\iota_i$ to test the composition on!

We see that the universal property massively reduces to the following:

> For every set $X$, there is a unique function $\mathcal{A}\to X$

The only solution to this in $\mathsf{Set}$ is $\mathcal{A}:=\emptyset$.

---

If you aren't satisfied with e.g. "the empty family of functions", consider that this is no more or less weird than the notion of 'empty function'.  Note that we can also extend the notion of coproduct to $I=\emptyset$ in another natural way. For any set $I$, we could define the coproduct of the $A_i$ to be the colimit of the functor $\mathfrak{D}(I)\to\mathsf{Set}$ that assigns $i\mapsto A_i$, $\mathrm{id}\to\mathrm{id}$, where $\mathfrak{D}(I)$ is the discrete category on the elements of $I$.

This definition agrees with the usual one for nonempty $I$, and for $I=\emptyset$ it gives us the same answer $\mathcal{A}=\emptyset$, as $\mathfrak{D}(I)$ is empty and the colimit of any empty diagram is the initial object of that category, when it exists, by similar reasoning (the universal property reduces).

If you haven't learn about (co)limits of diagrams yet, you may ignore the above.

Comment: thank you so much for your detail write up.  Equalizer and Coequalizer are next on the category menu.  Limits and Colimits comes shortly after I start the next chapter.

Comment: If you ever want more than one source to read from, while Emily Riehl's book is very good it is also quite hard at times and more on the terse side (as more advanced textbooks always are) so I'd recommend Leinster's Basic Category Theory (freely and legally available as a pdf on arxiv, just type it up)

Comment: thank you for the recommendation.  I know at one of my local uni, Leinster's book is also used for a grad algebra course.  My friend who took the course told me that the course does not go into details the way Arbib and Manes does, in  terms of the basic details.  I am sure I will go over both Riehl and Leinster's books eventually for personal review just to see what I am still missing in terms of the basics, that also includes the exercises.

Comment: I think the best definition of (co)limit is the one you give in terms of (co)cones. For then, the answer more or less jumps out.